# SQL Server & ASP.NET & C# : select 5 random images from top 20 images

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, localhost

I have a little SQL problem.

I want to select 5 random rows of the 20 rows with highest `ID`. How do I do that? At the moment my `SqlDataSource` just looks like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource25" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>"
     ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1.ProviderName %>"
     SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 5 * FROM [billeder] ORDER BY newid()">  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

which means I of course just gets 5 random from the entire table.

I would prefer to do it via the `SqlDataSource` as you can see here, but if it is only possible via codebehind that is fine aswell. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a subquery to get the top 20 by ID, then from this 20 you can select the top 5:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * 
FROM (  SELECT  TOP 20 * 
        FROM [billeder] 
        ORDER BY ID DESC
    ) AS t 
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

Comment: Thank you, this made it work! :) Thank everyone else for their fast support aswell, much appreciated guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  * from [billeder] where [yourPk] in 
(select top 5 percent [yourPk] from [billeder] order by newid())
```

yourPk is primarykey